# Handling popups while scraping with PhantomJS or other libraries

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs, codeceptjs

There are lots of libraries out there to scrape information from web pages. Some of them which I had a look are:

- http://phantomjs.org/
- http://webdriver.io/
- http://casperjs.org/
- http://www.nightmarejs.org/
- http://codecept.io/
- https://data-miner.io
- http://chaijs.com/

Surprisingly, none of them provide a way to scrape a popup window. Even if they do, I couldn't figure out how it's done.
The scenario is something like this:

```
-Visit a url (example.com)
-Fill login form
-Click login button
```

...and now, **webpage opens a popup** (an actual browser window) which I need to scrape.

Any suggestions or workarounds for popups?

Comment: In PhantomJS there is a callback to handle new browser window. You can read a short description and an example at http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-page-created.html

Answer (score 1):

webdriver.io offers change frame features, so in case your pop up has frame tags or iframe tags you can switch to it and test it. You can read more here 
http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/frame.html#Usage